# Create numpy array with fromiter

Tags: python, numpy, sqlite

I am trying to make numpy arrays from data stored in sqlite3 and have an issue with the strings.  From what I understand, fromiter is the most efficient way to accomplish this task.  After getting the data with cursor.fetchall(), the string is correct.  However after going into the numpy array it gets lost.

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

connection = sqlite3.connect('fermControlData.db')

with connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT Time, bTemp, aTemp, heaterStatus, gasMonitor, Location FROM dataLog WHERE beerName= 'Red Sled' ORDER BY Time"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data[0], type(data[0][5]))
    dataLog = np.fromiter(data, dtype=('f, f, f, i, i8, S'))
    print(dataLog[0])
```

And this is the output-

```
(1480890498.4052606, 65.53, 66.42, 0, 0.0, 'Warm1') <class 'str'>
(1480890496.0, 65.52999877929688, 66.41999816894531, 0, 0, b'')
```

As you can see the string 'Warm1' is getting converted to b' '.

Do you know why that happens and how to fix it so that the string is imported?

Many thanks!

Comment: when using `fromiter`, you have to give max size of strings. could you try `dtype=('f, f, f, i, i8, <U5')` ? BTW `i8` seems strange since corresponding data is a float.

Comment: `b'  '` is how Py3 displays bytestrings, the `S` dtype.  Try `U5` for the native unicode.

Comment: Thanks!  U5 did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in numpy arrays are fixed lenght and in the case of `fromiter` you have to specify that length in advance. E.g. with `dtype=('f, f, f, i, i8, S5')`.